# card code is not validating in authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am developing a web application. Here I have implemented the authorize.net payment gateway.
But here the cave code is not validating correctly. If I give wrong card code the payment results in success But i need the result as payment declained

Does anyone know this?
 see the code

```
                    "x_version"         => "3.1",

                    "x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",

                    "x_delim_char"      => "|",

                    "x_relay_response"  => "FALSE",

                    "x_type"            => "AUTH_CAPTURE",

                    "x_method"          => "CC",

                    "x_card_num"        => $card_number,

                    "x_exp_date"        => $exp_date,

                    "x_amount"          => $amount,

                    "x_description"     => "Live Transaction",

                    "x_card_code"       => $ccv,



                    "x_first_name"      => $bill_name,

                    "x_address"         => $bill_address,

                    "x_city"            => $bill_city,

                    "x_state"           => $bill_state,

                    "x_zip"             => $bill_zip,

                    "x_country"         => $bill_country,

                    "x_phone"           => $bill_phone,

                    "x_email"           => $email,



                   "x_ship_to_first_name"       => $ship_name,

                    "x_ship_to_address"         => $ship_address,

                    "x_ship_to_city"            => $ship_city,

                    "x_ship_to_state"           => $ship_state,

                    "x_ship_to_zip"             => $ship_zip,

                    "x_ship_to_country"         => $ship_country,

                    "x_ship_to_phone"           => $ship_phone

                    // Additional fields can be added here as outlined in the AIM integration

                    // guide at: http://developer.authorize.net

                );



                // This section takes the input fields and converts them to the proper format

                // for an http post.  For example: "x_login=username&x_tran_key=a1B2c3D4"

                $post_string = "";

                foreach( $post_values as $key => $value )

                    { $post_string .= "$key=" . urlencode( $value ) . "&"; }

                $post_string = rtrim( $post_string, "& " );




                // The following section provides an example of how to add line item details to
                // the post string.  Because line items may consist of multiple values with the
                // same key/name, they cannot be simply added into the above array.
                //
                // This section is commented out by default.





                foreach( $line_items as $value )
                    { $post_string .= "&x_line_item=" . urlencode( $value ); }


                // This sample code uses the CURL library for php to establish a connection,

                // submit the post, and record the response.

                // If you receive an error, you may want to ensure that you have the curl

                // library enabled in your php configuration

                $request = curl_init($post_url); // initiate curl object

                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response

                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)

                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data

                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.

                    $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response

                    // additional options may be required depending upon your server configuration

                    // you can find documentation on curl options at http://www.php.net/curl_setopt

                curl_close ($request); // close curl object

                // This line takes the response and breaks it into an array using the specified delimiting character

                $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);
```

Comment: You have done something wrong. You need to post some code or similar in order for someone to help you with *what* you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a code error. If you want the payment to be declined when the CVV number is incorrect you need to set it in your Authorize.Net control panel. It is found under the security settings.

Answer (score 2):

You problem might be related to some incorrect settings in the authorize.net account. Check the following:

1. Make sure that the transaction version is set to 3.1. You can do that from `Settings->Transaction Version->Submit`
2. Set the `Card Code Verification` rejection settings and select `N` and `U` options. To do that, go to `Settings->Card Code Verification`
3. Make sure that the `x_version` field is set to "3.1" and that the `x_card_code` contains CCV number.

Hope this helps.

More details:
https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A546&impressions=false